# SQL Server, complex query

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, select, group-by

I have an Azure SQL Database table which is filled by importing XML-files.

The order of the files is random so I could get something like this:

```
ID  | Name  | DateFile | IsCorrection | Period | Other data
1   | Mr. A | March, 1 | false        | 3      | Foo
20  | Mr. A | March, 1 | true         | 2      | Foo
13  | Mr. A | Apr, 3   | true         | 2      | Foo
4   | Mr. B | Feb, 1   | false        | 2      | Foo
```

This table is joined with another table, which is also joined with a 3rd table.

I need to get the join of these 3 tables for the person with the newest data, based on Period, DateFile and Correction.

In my above example, Id=1 is the original data for Period 3, I need this record.
But in the same file was also a correction for Period 2 (Id=20) and in the file of April, the data was corrected again (Id=13).

So for Period 3, I need Id=1, for Period 2 I need Id=13 because it has the last corrected data and I need Id=4 because it is another person.

I would like to do this in a view, but using a stored procedure would not be a problem.

I have no idea how to solve this. Any pointers will be much appreciated.

EDIT:
My datamodel is of course much more complex than this sample. DateFile and Period are DateTime types in the table. Actually Period is two DateTime columns: StartPeriod and EndPeriod.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the sample data as DDL+DML (create table and insert into statements) and desired results.

Comment: Are your date fields really just month, day format and not a real date(date/time)?  What denotes between period 2, 2016 and period 2, 2017?

Comment: I updated my post. Hopefully, it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well looking at your data I believe we can disregard the IsCorrection column and just pick the latest column for each user/period.
Lets start by ordering the rows placing the latest on top :

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Period, Name ORDER by DateFile DESC), *
```

And from this result you select all with row number 1:

```
;with numberedRows as (
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Period, Name ORDER by DateFile DESC) as rowIndex, *
)

select * from numberedRows where rowIndex=1
```

The PARTITION BY tells ROW_NUMBER() to reset the counter whenever it encounters change in the columns Period and Name. The ORDER BY tells the ROW_NUMBER() that we want th newest row to be number 1 and then older posts afterwards. We only need the latest row.

The WITH declares a "common table expression" which is a kind of subquery or temporary table.

Not knowing your exact data, I might recommend you something wrong, but you should be able to join your with last query with other tables to get your desired result.

Something like:

```
;with numberedRows as (
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Period, Name ORDER by DateFile DESC) as rowIndex, *
)

select * from numberedRows a 
JOIN periods b on b.empId = a.Id 
JOIN msg c on b.msgId = c.Id
where a.rowIndex=1
```

Comment: Thanks, Hendrik. This `PARTITION` and `WITH` stuff is new to me. I'm catching up my reading. I understand the `PARTITION` part, but not yet the last two steps. If my query is `SELECT a.Name, b.Period, c.DateFile FROM emp a JOIN periods b on b.empId = a.Id JOIN msg c on b.msgId = c.Id` how to merge your code into it? And again this query is simplified.

Comment: Thanks it is working now. I'll mark your post as the answer.